# Problem adding Contact with new API

Tags: android, new-operator, contacts

I am trying to add a new contact to my contact list using the new ContactContract API via my application. I have the following method based on the Contact Manager  example on android dev.

```
    private static void addContactCore(Context context, String accountType, String accountName, String name, String phoneNumber, int phoneType) throws RemoteException, OperationApplicationException {

    ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> ops = new ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation>();

    //Add contact type
    ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTENT_URI)
            .withValue(ContactsContract.RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE, accountType)
            .withValue(ContactsContract.RawContacts.ACCOUNT_NAME, accountName)
            .build());

    //Add contact name
    ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
            .withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0)
            .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
            .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.DISPLAY_NAME, (!name.toLowerCase().equals("unavailable") && !name.equals("")) ? name : phoneNumber)
            .build());

    //Add phone number
    ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
            .withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0)
            .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
            .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER, phoneNumber)
            .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE, phoneType)
            .build());

    //Add contact
    context.getContentResolver().applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, ops);
}
```

In one example I have the flowing values for the parameters.
accountType:com.google
accountName:(my google account email)
name:Mike
phoneNumber:5555555555
phoneType:3

The call to the function returns normally without any exception being thrown however the contact is no where to be found in the contact manager on my phone. There is also no contact with that information on my phone already. Does anyone have any insight into what I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the display options to display the contacts associated with the particular account.

Comment: This worked for me. More specifically, go to Contacts -> Display Options -> [account] and check "All other Contacts"

Answer (score 0):

You probably also need to add it to the "System Group: My Contacts" group.